# wordpress stylesheet loading

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer-7

In IE7, display: inline-block doesn't work.

In my wordpress site in style.css, I have defined:

```
#footerlinks li {display:inline-block;list-style-type:none;height:25px;}
```

style.css is coming from functions.php using:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
```

For IE7, I want to use:

```
#footerlinks li {_height:25px;zoom:1;*display:inline;list-style-type:none;}
```

What code should I use and where should I put it ?

Kind Regards
R

Answer (score 2):

The offical way, to use conditional comments would be:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/my-plugin/style.css' );
global $wp_styles;
$wp_styles->add_data( 'my-style', 'conditional', 'lte IE 7' );
```

source: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10618#comment:6

Answer (score 0):

In your header.php after wp_head()

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="my.ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

That's it. Read more about conditional includes on quirksmode: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Answer (score 0):

The best eay to handle this is using a conditional stylesheet.  In the `<head>` section of your header.php include the following;

```
<!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/ie7.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
```

Make sure it is **after** the `<?php wp_head(); ?>` call or the style will not override the styles.css value.

Then you add your;

```
#footerlinks li {_height:25px;zoom:1;*display:inline;list-style-type:none;}
```

to a file called ie7.css and place it in the css directory (or wherever you want, that's based on my example).

This will be applied to IE7 only.